# Google Actions - Personality

Tags: google-apps, actions-on-google

I'm in the final phase of building my app and I was wondering other than the 3 personalities I have offered to ne are there any more or candour own be made. If so how can this be done?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the templates, you can only use one of the pre-defined templates. If you are interested in creating a more unique conversational experience, you would need to write your own action.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Nick, if I were the write me on own would this be done on google actions as I can't find a option for this